# Import error with module _ssl for Python 3.3

Tags: python, ssl, importerror, python-3.3

I am programming in Python 3.3 on the latest version of Ubuntu.  I am writing code for a project involving a library that works with Twitter. Here is the output from the terminal I have:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tryout.py", line 2, in <module>
  import twitter
File "/home/owner/Documents/twitter/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
  from .stream import TwitterStream
File "/home/owner/Documents/twitter/stream.py", line 9, in <module>
  from ssl import SSLError
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/ssl.py", line 60, in <module>
  import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named '_ssl'
```

I've been looking around to find a solution for the _ssl error but can't seem to find one that I could follow.