# python3.3.1 ssl module

Tags: python

I attempted to put push message to apple push notification server via python ssl socket.
but fail to do this on python 3.3.1.

```
Python 3.3.1 (default, Apr  9 2013, 14:40:22) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import ssl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "./ssl.py", line 60, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named '_ssl'
>>>
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214791.

Answer (score 0):

this happens when you not install python3 properly (missing dependencies), for more information, [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171210/building-python-and-more-on-missing-modules)

basicallyyou have to `sudo apt-get install <package_name>`, 
`<package_name>` is missing module name with leading dash that you'll find when install python with `make test` from source and it fails unexpected. `<package_name>` is normally ends with `-dev` suffix. and more often it with `lib` prefix too. so you can search it with `apt-cache search <package_name>.*-dev$`.

then you can test with `make test` under python source directory.
At the end, reinstall your python with `./configure` `make` and `make insall`

as to your question, issue `sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`. then reinsall python.