# test test_urllibnet failed in Linux

Tags: python-3.x

I want to install Python. I tried both Python3.3 and Python3.4 I downloaded the file from https://www.python.org/download/releases/  and followed the instructions.
I executed :

```
./configure
make
```

successful. But when execute :

```
make test
```

it failed for test_urllibnet.

So according the README file if executed  for Python3.4:

```
./python -m test -v test_urllibnet
== CPython 3.4.0 (default, Apr 16 2014, 16:38:06) [GCC 4.8.1]
==   Linux-3.11.0-15-generic-x86_64-with-debian-wheezy-sid little-endian
==   hash algorithm: siphash24 64bit
==   /home/bernard/Python/Python3.4/Python-3.4.0/build/test_python_27532
Testing with flags: sys.flags(debug=0, inspect=0, interactive=0, optimize=0, dont_write_bytecode=0, no_user_site=0, no_site=0, ignore_environment=0, verbose=0, bytes_warning=0, quiet=0, hash_randomization=1, isolated=0)
[1/1] test_urllibnet
test_urllibnet skipped -- Use of the 'network' resource not enabled
1 test skipped:
    test_urllibnet
```

So now it skipped because the 'network' is not enabled. But how to enable the 'network'? I could not find it.

On a different computer I try to install Python3.3 with all most the same error.

```
./python -m test -v test_urllibnet
== CPython 3.3.5 (default, Apr 24 2014, 17:18:29) [GCC 4.6.3]
==   Linux-3.5.0-38-generic-x86_64-with-debian-wheezy-sid little-endian
==   /home/bernard/Downloads/Python-3.3.5/build/test_python_6523
Testing with flags: sys.flags(debug=0, inspect=0, interactive=0, optimize=0, dont_write_bytecode=0, no_user_site=0, no_site=0, ignore_environment=0, verbose=0, bytes_warning=0, quiet=0, hash_randomization=1)
[1/1] test_urllibnet
test_urllibnet skipped -- Use of the 'network' resource not enabled
1 test skipped:
    test_urllibnet
Those skips are all expected on linux.
```

Notice this should be Ok for Linux. But in Python3.3 the statement

```
Python 3.3.5 (default, Apr 24 2014, 17:18:29) 
    [GCC 4.6.3] on linux
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import ssl
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.3/ssl.py", line 60, in <module>
        import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
    ImportError: No module named '_ssl'
```

So it is not Ok. The solution in [python3.3.1 ssl module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901357/python3-3-1-ssl-module) looks quite similar, but does not work for me.

I looked into 
[Building Python and more on missing modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171210/building-python-and-more-on-missing-modules)
but also without result.

Just installing software, here Python, is escalating and gets real complex.

Comment: Happened to me with Python3.6 and OpenSuse. Fixed with installation of openssl-devel lib.

Answer (score -1):

No solution for me, just a work-around. Installing just Python gets to complex and take to much time. Others seems to have the same problem.

The work around is just use the pre-installed Python2.7 which works. I tried to avoid Python2.7 as much as possible, but now I am obliged to use it. This answer may help to prevent people spend to much time in solving a problem which is hard to solve.